# "strtotime('tomorrow') - time()" OR "strtotime('tomorrow') - strtotime('now')" will not give the correct time until upcoming midnight

Tags: php, date, time, countdown

I'm trying to do a simple countdown, but it's giving the wrong time:

```
$time_seconds_view = strtotime('tomorrow') - time(); echo date("H" . " \h\o\u\\r\s\, " . "i" . " \m\i\\n\u\\t\\e\s\, \a\\n\d " . "s" . " \s\\e\c\o\\n\d\s", $time_seconds_view);
```

is spitting out `00 hours, 30 minutes, and 00 seconds`

even though `date_default_timezone_set($this->session->userdata('timezone'));` is set to `America/Phoenix`

it should be spitting out `07 hours, 30 minutes, and 00 seconds`

it's as if PHP is not taking account that I've changed the default timezone.

Anything I'm doing wrong? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DateTime. It's much better for date math.

```
$tomorrow = new DateTime('tomorrow');
$now = new DateTime();
$diff = $tomorrow->diff($now);
echo $diff->format("%h hours, %i minutes, %s seconds");
// 7 hours, 12 minutes, 53 seconds
```

[See in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/3Ogf9V)

Comment: Wow, thanks! Works. What was wrong with my code, though? So confused on why it wouldn't work correctly.

Comment: Also, how was your code [your demo in action] able to get the right timezone from me?

Comment: Not sure. But time(), strtotime(), date(), etc, were not meant for date math so it's easy for things to be off for non-obvious reasons. Fortunately DateTime() solves this issue for us.